# Pull data from regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all

I am trying to split this text up into an array using regular expressions, but my regular expression isn't strong enough to do it.

**Note:** There can be one or more `{elseif}` lines just like PHP

```
{if 'Fred' == 'Fred'}
    Welcome Sir.
{elseif 'Fred' == 'Wilma'}
    Welcome Ma'am.
{else}
    Welcome, whatever you are.
{/if}
```

The final array I am trying to achieve would look like this:

```
array(
    [0] => array(
        [0] => if 'Fred' == 'Fred'
        [1] => elseif 'Fred' == 'Wilma'
        [2] => else
    ),
    [1] => array(
        [0] => Welcome Sir.
        [1] => Welcome Ma'am.
        [2] => Welcome, whatever you are.
    )
);
```

I am using this regular expression to do it:

```
preg_match_all("/\{(if|elseif|else|\/if).*\}(.*)\{(elseif|else|\/if).*\}/isU", $section, $matches);
```

but that outputs this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => {if 'Fred' == 'Fred'}
    Welcome Sir.
{elseif 'Fred' == 'Wilma'}
            [1] => {else}
    Welcome, whatever you are.
{/if}
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => if
            [1] => else
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => 
    Welcome Sir.

            [1] => 
    Welcome, whatever you are.

        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => elseif
            [1] => /if
        )

)
```

Can someone please help me? thanks!

Comment: Did you try to change the flag in preg_match_all_call ? Like : preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);

Comment: I tired, not sure if that helps or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your if/else things will start exactly after the second bracket({)

```
preg_match_all("/(\{(?:if|elseif|else)[^\}]*\})\s*([^{]+)\s+/mi", $section, $matches);
```

Comment: That looks like it will do it!

Answer (score 1):

This seems to give the results you're looking for:

```
$str = "{if 'Fred' == 'Fred'}
    Welcome Sir.
{elseif 'Fred' == 'Wilma'}
    Welcome Ma'am.
{else}
    Welcome, whatever you are.
{/if}";

preg_match_all('/{((if|elsif|else).*)}/', $str, $matches_conditionals);
preg_match_all('/}[\n\s]*(.*)\s*{/imU', $str, $matches_contents);

$result = array($matches_conditionals[1], $matches_contents[1]);

print_r($result);
```

Comment: Thanks HamZa.  Something ate my returns.